# NullPointerException in the implementation of Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException when I attempt to add an object with InsertFront() method. The DList code is:

```
public class DList {
 protected DListNode head;
  protected int size;

protected DListNode newNode(Object item, DListNode prev, DListNode next) {
    return new DListNode(item, prev, next);
  }

public DList() {
    head=newNode(null,head,head);
    size=0;
  }


public void insertFront(Object item) {
     head.next.prev=newNode(item, head, head.next);
     head.next=head.next.prev;
     size++;
}
```

However, this error no longer shows up as soon as I change the DList constructor to this:

```
 public DList() {
        head=newNode(null,head,head);
        head.prev=head;
        head.next=head;
        size=0;
      }
```

Now, I do understand that assigning the head.next & head.prev values solved the problem; But I don't understand what was the need for stating this seperately when I already assigned the 'head' variable as the prev and next nodes in the 1st line of the constructor:

```
head=newNode(null,head,head);
```

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

In the initial constructor, this may not be doing what you think it is:

```
head=newNode(null,head,head);
```

Note that `head` is `null` initially, so the call is really something like this:

```
head=newNode(null,null /*prev*/, null /*next*/);
```

In `insertFront` you try to reference `head.next.prev`, but since `head.next` was `null` you get an exception.

Another way to think of your old constructor is to decompose it into 2 lines:

```
DListNode temp=newNode(null,head,head); // remember that head is null here
head=temp;
```

The method arguments are evaluated before the variable assignment.